# Using setData with merge: true in the new FlutterFire API

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am updating my old flutter code with the new FlutterFire API. I use a `setData` with `merge: true` in one of my functions to update some document fields that are saved in a Map. I do change `setData` to `set`, but I get an error with the new FlutterFire plugin that "merge" isn't defined. I found in the migration docs that

> setData/set now supports SetOptions to merge data/fields (previously this accepted a Map)

The document reference also says:

```
/// If [SetOptions] are provided, the data will be merged into an existing


/// document instead of overwriting.
  Future<void> set(Map<String, dynamic> data, [SetOptions options]) {
    assert(data != null);
    return _delegate.set(
        _CodecUtility.replaceValueWithDelegatesInMap(data), options);
  }
```

In my original code, I am saving new values in a `Map<String, dynamic>` called `changedvalues` and then I use `setData(changedValues, merge:true)`

So, How do I provide SetOptions to make sure merge is true and only the fields in the changedValues are updated in the document?

Comment: As far as I can see, the [API documentation for set()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/set.html), which you are now using, shows that it accepts a `Map<String, dynamic>` as the first argument.  What's the specific problem you're running into with using that?  Please edit the question to show the code you're working with, and the specific error that you're seeing.

Comment: What have you tried? What's preventing you from doing this?

Comment: I just edited the question.

Comment: That just seems like your old code. You posted the new documentation so you know that  is no longer valid. What have you tried in providing the new `SetOptions`?

Comment: That's my question. I don't know how to provide [SetOptions] to the new "set" function. So, I haven't tried anything. I can't just make up something.

Comment: You have the documentation that shows you what to provide. There is no need to make anything up. Programming is not a guessing game. I recommend trying something first. The linter will tell you when something is wrong, so there isn't even a need to build to find if you did it right.

Comment: I mean I tried typing options, setOptions, etc. but the linter just told me they are all invalid. That's why I thought maybe I was just guessing. Anyways, I'll just use "update" instead. I was hoping someone would just know and tell me what the proper code would be if I wanted to still use "set"

Comment: What is unclear about the documentation that you don't understand?

Comment: Well the documentation says that "setData/set now supports SetOptions to merge data/fields (previously this accepted a Map)" and then "If [SetOptions] are provided, the data will be merged into an existing document instead of overwriting."  What I can't figure out is How to provide "SetOptions". Didn't I already say this properly?

Comment: Look at what the function declaration says, not just the text of the documentation. The declaration tells you how to use the function.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You have to do the following:

```
set({"name" : "akbarB"}, SetOptions(merge : true))
```

Comment: I used this to get the "append" functionality with FirebaseFirestore documents. Clear, short and gets the job done +1

Comment: How is this not in the documentation yet. Unbelievable